# Translate HTML JSDoc for VS Code

Tags: typescript, plugins, comments, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I've been looking for a plugin that translate JsDoc to HTML, annotations like @memberOf, @params...

Does anyone know something about it?

This is what I mean:
[image]

Comment: SO doesn't usually give technology recommendations. We can help you with specific programming problems if you have any.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I became crazy looking for this and I didn't know where should I ask, probably I will develop it for VsCode.